# /dev/nvme0n1p3 ubuntu 20.04 does not booting up

Tags: chmod

I'm in a trouble. I've changed diretory "usr" using command "chmod" and now my laptop Is crashed. I'm  having the followed message in a Black screen when it's turning on: "/dev/nvme0n1p3: clean, 9020526/15597568 filés, 35451225/62378496 blocks". I don't know how can I fix it. Someone can help me please?

Comment: Reinstall the system.

Comment: Ok. Thanks I'll do that